# quitar tildes de textos consultados de sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

tengo el siguiente código.

```
public static String sqliteSinTilde (String campo)
{

    String result = "";

    result = " REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER("+campo+"),'á','a'), 'é','e'),'í','i'),'ó','o'),'ú','u'),'Ñ','ñ'),'Á','a'),'É','e'),'Í','i'),'Ó','o'),'Ú','u')" ;


    return result;
}
```

al usar este método.. me devuelve esto.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(DESCRIP),'Ã¡','a'), 'Ã©','e'),'Ã­','i'),'Ã³','o'),'Ãº','u'),'Ã','Ã±'),'Ã','a'),'Ã','e'),'Ã','i'),'Ã','o'),'Ã','u')
```

que estoy haciendo mal ?

**SOLUCIÓN**

```
 public static String sqliteSinTilde (String campo)
    {

        String result = "";

        result = " REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER("+campo+"),'á','a'), 'é','e'),'í','i'),'ó','o'),'ú','u'),'Ñ','ñ'),'Á','a'),'É','e'),'Í','i'),'Ó','o'),'Ú','u')" ;
        //String Str2 = "";
        String Str3 = "";

        try {
            //Str2 = new String( result.getBytes( "UTF-8" ));
            //System.out.println("Returned Value " + Str2 );
            Str3 = new String (result.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ));
            System.out.println("Returned Value " + Str3 );
        } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("Unsupported character set");
        }

        return Str3;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que tener la misma codificación en ambos, pero si no la tienes tendrás que convertir el String, usa esto:

```
byte ptext[] = myStringResult.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

myStringResult es tu String,

o si la codificación es al revés invierte ISO-8859-1 por UTF-8 o la codificación que necesites.

Saludos.

Comment: claro necesito lo que me comentas.. pero estando en androidstudio ..  getBytes no me reconoce.. por lo que me lo marca como error.

Comment: ya pude ver un ejemplo..  lo voy a  probar y te comento.. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ésto se debe a las diferencias entre los charsets entre la página y la base de datos. Por ejemplo, si la base está configurada con un charset ISO-8859-1 y el sitio con charset UTF-8, obtendrás este resultado.

La solución es establecer la misma configuración de charset para ambos servidores (web y base de datos).

Comment: veo que la bd de sqlite es grande .. habría alguna forma de hacerlo por código?

Comment: Si en la base de datos podés ver lso caracteres especiales sin problemas (es decir, tiene un charset compatible), probá cambiar el charset del sitio para que sea compatible con el de la base de datos. A veces, esto implica cambiar el charset de los archivos que interactúan con la db, incluyendo JS y C#